# @ WebMvcTest loading application context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I have a `GreetingController`

```
@Controller
    public class GreetingController {
        @RequestMapping("/greeting")
        public @ResponseBody String greeting() {
            return "Hello, same to you";
        }
    }
```

and `GreetingControllerTest`

```
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
public class WebMockTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void greetingShouldReturnMessageFromService() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/greeting")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, same to you")));
    }
}
```

I am running the test in intelliJ hoping that it will **not** load the application context, but it starts with launching the application.

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

{"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":..........
```

As per [spring doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) `we can narrow the tests to only the web layer by using @WebMvcTest.` Does this mean that it still loads the application context? Or maybe I did not understand it correctly.

Comment: It loads a minimal context, so yes it will load something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `@WebMvcTest` you still get an application context, but not the full application context.

The started Spring Test Context only contains beans that are relevant for testing your Spring MVC components: `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `Converter`, `Filter`, `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Injecting `MockMvc` using `@Autowired MockMvc mockMvc;` also indicates that you are working with a Spring context and the JUnit Jupiter extension (`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class` which is part of `@WebMvcTest`) takes care to resolve your fields by retrieving them from the Test context.

If you still don't want a Spring Test context to be started, you can write a unit test using only JUnit and Mockito. With such tests, you would only be able to verify the business logic of your controller and not things like: correct HTTP response, path variable and query parameter resolving, exception handling with different HTTP status, etc.

You can read more on the different [Spring Boot Test slices here](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/) and on how to [use `MockMvc` to test your web layer](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/).

Comment: This is what I would expec,t but I got COMPLETE context.

Comment: Seeing the Spring Boot banner in the logs is fine. This is not an indicator that the entire context is launched, it's a subset of the entire `ApplicationContext`. If you want to verify this, try to inject persistence-related beans to your `@WebMvcTest` and you'll see the test fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the test bootup the WHOLE CONTEXT(i KNOW it because it tried to load all my @Repository code), and i found a workaround for this, it's very nasty:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes ={Controller.TestConfig.class})
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
class ControllerTest {

@Configuration
public static class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public Controller controller() {
        return new Controller();
    }
}
```

I know substituting the actual Spring context with a test one is kind of a makeshift solution, but i cant think of anything else.