# Why @WebMvcTest(MyCotroller.class) creates mongo repositories and in general boots complete application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have simple @RestController and I have tried to write slice test for it using @WebMvcTest like this

```
@RestController
public class ValidationController {
    private final ValidationService validationService;
...}


@WebMvcTest(ValidationController.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "org.springframework.web=DEBUG"
})
public class ValidationControllerTest  {
@MockBean
ValidationService validationService;
```

but for whatever resons, app context fails due to..... missing XService bean which is totally MVN unrelated compoennt and is not used in the controller.
I though that `@WebMvcTest(ValidationController.class)` will boot only web layer with single explicitly mentioned controller, but for whatever reasons, it works more like `@SpringBootTest`

What do work as I expect is this

```
@WebMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ValidationController.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "org.springframework.web=DEBUG"
})
public class ValidationControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {
```

Why is that? Is this a bug or somehow expected behavior?

My expectations were to both snippets to work the same way. Here answer somehow confirms it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64923895/1527544 but I see a different behavior.

Comment: Which is probably because you have some `@EnableMongoRepositories` or additional configuration on your `@SpringBootApplication` class (or an `@Import`). If that happens the test support has no way of excluding it from being loaded.

Comment: That is true, but then how to organize application to make @WebMvcTest to work out of the box ????? After all, SpringBootApplication is not a "web component" thus it should be ignored imo anyway

Comment: No it isn't ignored as that as the root `@Configuration` and still can contain essential things for the web or specific exclusions that need to be active. Additional configuration should go on a separate `@Configuration` class so that the testing infrastructure can exclude it.

Comment: But the "additional configuration" as you said, will be included on @SpringBootApplication anyway as it is required for normal application mode. Should it be explicitly defined then to always be skipped on test profile or what?

Comment: No you don't need to explicitly skip it. You just need it to be on a separate `@Configuration` class, which will be excluded automatically by the test bootstrapping.

Comment: Crap, looks like I have to dig really deep into the documentation regarding tests. In the meantime i will have to stick to ContextConfiguration. But indeed, it changes the behavior of test context when I have moved all additional annotation to a separate config class and left only SpringBootApplication behind. However, I have different issue now which is an another topic. Thank you.